# How to get the type of an array-property?

Tags: .net, reflection

I have something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar[] Bars{get; set;}
}


public class Bar
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I start reflecting:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bars");
```

so far so good. I want to reflect deeper:

```
Type type = _propertyInfo .PropertyType; // this gives me that the type is Bar[]
```

The `type` is `Bar[]`, but it is not possible to reflect on `type` to look for property `Name`.
Is there a way to figure out the trype without the array? Or another way to find the single type of Bar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (type.HasElementType)
    Console.WriteLine(type.GetElementType().Name);
```

I wrote the HasElementType because I'm guessing you are also going to need to figure out if your element is an array.

Comment: accepted this one cause HasElementType is indeed good to know as well

Comment: Nice & easy way to find it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
type.GetElementType().Name
```